# Merging attribute features based on matching field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-pro, attribute-table

I have parcel data for a city where my goal is to merge rows which have the same parcel number ID. I have 53,000 total parcels, with about 6 thousand rows that have one duplicate. So far I have been manually merging rows, but now realizing it will take me forever to match these 6,000+ pairs of data. I've attached a screenshot below of one example. I am wondering if there is a code that exists that will merge certain rows based on a duplicate value in one field? I ran a script in the 'test' field that shows me which values have the same parcel number. Now I need to merge these matching values via the 'parcelnumb' field.

[image: This screenshots shows highlighted OBJECTID 46505 and 50818 with matching parcel number fields.]

Answer (score 2):

[Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) your features. Your original parcel data is the input, and use 'parcelnumb' as the dissolve field. Make sure multipart features are allowed (this is the default).